# asp.net core 2.0 not able to post a simple form

Tags: c#, http-post, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I am trying to learn **Asp.net Core 2.0** and following a tutorial, I created a very simple form with only 1 property, the name of the **Customer**. I debugged with breakpoints I am not even able to hit the **PostAsync** method in **CreateModel**

**CreateModel**

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    [BindProperty]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Page();

        _db.Customers.Add(Customer);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("/");
    }
}
```

**Create.cs.html**

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.CreateModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<p>Enter your name: </p>

<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"/>
    <div>Name : <input asp-for="Customer.Name"/></div>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

@section Scripts{ 
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**Customer**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base (options)    { }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

**ConfigureServices method in my Startup class**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("dbname"));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

**Update**

> Here is the full project on GitHub to reproduce the issue : https://github.com/touseefbsb/aspnet_post

When I enter more than 10 characters, it never hits the breakpoint in postasync method, and nothing happens on the page as well, it is supposed to show me the validation error on UI but it does not.

When I enter a name less than 10 character and press submit, it tries to submit ( the breakpoint in postasync is hit ) but then it tried to redirect, I get following page of error :

[image: error stacktrace]

**Full StackTrace** :

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.RedirectToPageResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext context, RedirectToPageResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToPageResult.ExecuteResult(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeResultAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: it shows some kind of error? Your code has no error.

Comment: I do not get any error I keep clicking the submit button and nothing happens, I have a breakpoint on 1st line of my PostAsync method and that breakpoint is not being hit.

Comment: I tested your code everything works fine. In the run button chose the name of your project and when you run the application maybe you can see in cmd some kind of error.

Comment: I have updated my question with the GitHub repo , you can reproduce the issue by cloning the repo @Llazar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if Razor has generated an antiforgery token for you.

When you submit a form this token has to be validated and if your cookies don't have the expected one the submission gets rejected.

**Update:**

The `RedirectToPage` method requires full path to a page.

The form submission prevented by JavaScript when there is an input error but it won't show up because `<div asp-validation-summary="All">` lacks the closing `</div>`.

Comment: and how can I check that?

Comment: Well, it was just a guess and it doesn't seem to be the case. For the redirection to work, though, you have to specify the full path `RedirectToPage("/Index")`.

Comment: Yes @Ranopano you're right. I have added redirect in my solution but doesn't help to hit the breakpoint.

Comment: @touseefbsb, you seem to have forgotten to add the closing div there: `<div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>`. Without that javascript validation cannot display errors but still prevents the form from submitting when you enter the invalid number or characters.

Comment: @Ranopano yes you are right please add this </div> closing tag and /Index solutions to your answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1):

I just cloned your app and it's working fine. It's saving the data in InMemoryDatabase as needed. You can see the result in cmd [image: cmd execution].

see the other foto to for the breakpoint[image: breakpoint photo]

Comment: then is it not hitting the break point ? it doesnt make any sense,bcz it has to execute the postasync method in order to reach the saveasync method.

Comment: have you tried placing a breakpoint, is it hitting the breakpoint in your ide?

Comment: I have edited my answer see the second photo. Clean your cache in your browser.

Comment: I have tried again and updated my question as well please have a look @Llazar

Comment: I don't see any changes.

Comment: please reload the page and see the update part at the end of the question I have added some stacktrace with some info

Comment: See my second photo carefully. Add `/Index` to `RedirectPage`

Comment: But I don't understand you first says that you cannot hit breakpoint and how redirect can stop you to make a breakpoint???

Comment: I have mentioned 2 cases.
case1 : I enter less than 10 chars and I hot the breakpoint.
case2 : I enter more than 10 chars ( which is invalid and should show error of not valid ) in this case nothing happens, and postasync does not execute.

Comment: How just a redirect cannot allow to make a breakpoint? Anyway you have the solution you want it.